# Migrating to postgresql from SQL Server

Tags: postgresql

We are migrating from SQL Server to PostgreSQL. We have table structure as below

- Table name: Users
- Column names: Id, FirstName, LastName etc.

But, I am getting error as relation `Users` does not exist. If I rename the table to `users` it works. same happens with `columnames`.

Is there any solution if I don't need to rename my entire table names and column names. I tried:

```
hibernate.dialect= org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL94Dialect this property.
```

But still it's not working. Please help.

Comment: How are you doing the migration? the problem is in postgres to use capitalize tablename/fieldname you need to use double quotes `"` Like `"FirstName"` other wise postgresql thing they are lowercase.

Comment: Yeah. In my Java class I am using like this       
        @Column(name="\"Email\"")
 private String email;  But I need to make such changes a lot more places. I am looking for any property by which I can avoid this overhead.

Comment: Again how are you doing the migration?

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't use keywords as identifiers
2. In PostgreSQL make all identifiers snake_case

These are rules you need to live by in Postgres land. Your IDE should be able to do this refactoring for you easily

Answer (score 0):

If you do not use quotes while creating tables and columns in postgresql it is converted into lowercase,
So while creating the database you need to take care to add quotes if you want the same case.
Also,While specifing in hibernate mapping file you need to use quot keyword for table and columns mapped